# Find a sequence $(s_n)$ such that for any $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$, $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ where $s_n = a + b(n-1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics

I’m fairly sure such a sequence should exist. I’ve tried devising a sequence using primes or fibannoci numbers but haven’t been able to make progress.

Comment: Your quantifiers are hard to follow.  Are you saying that for any two natural number $a,b$ you want to find some $n$ such that your sequence has this form at $s_n$?  If so....the list of pairs $(a,b)$ is countable, so fix a bijection with $\mathbb N$ and define $s_n$ accordingly.

Comment: Note;  you don't even need a bijection, just an injection from the pairs to $\mathbb N$.  For instance, consider $(a,b)\mapsto 2^a\times 3^b$.  Now just define $s_{2^a3^b}=a+b(2^a3^b-1)$.  You can define $s_n$ however you like for other values of $n$.

Comment: Im saying I want a sequence such that no matter the choice of a and b, there will be some n where the equality is satisfied. I edited the question to hopefully make it more clear

Comment: then the sequence I provided should work.

Comment: If you want a single definition, try $s_n=v_2(n)+v_3(n)\times (n-1)$ where, as usual, $v_p(n)$ denotes the order to which a prime $p$ divides $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:  Since the possible pairs $(a,b)$ form a countable set, we can identify them with natural numbers, or with a subset of the natural numbers.  One simple way to do that is via the function $(a,b)\mapsto 2^a\times 3^b$.   That suffices to allow us to construct a sequence $s_n$ that works.

For instance:  $$s_n=v_2(n)+v_3(n)\times (n-1)$$

Where, as usual, $v_p(n)$ denotes the order to which a prime $p$ divides $n$.  Thus $v_2(2)=1$, $v_3(18)=2$, $v_7(11)=0$ and so on.

This sequence suffices.  In particular, given any pair $(a,b)$ of natural numbers, we have $s_{2^a3^b}=a+b\times (n-1)$ as desired.

Of course, this $n$ is not defined uniquely by $(a,b)$.  If $n$ works, then so does $5n$, for instance.  But uniqueness wasn't specified in the post.